# magento 2 grunt less don't see changes in few files

Tags: magento2, less, grunt

I have problem with Grunt watch. All works good but for example for _theme.css, but don't see any changes after I changing _extend.less what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I don't know why grunt exec create all files as symbolink link except _extend, I created symbolik link manually and all works perfect